# C# to Javascript: What the equivalent of `new MultipartFormDataContent();`

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this legacy C# code (I don't know C#) and I need to write the same functionality in Javascript (I know JS very well). So the C# code is:

```
static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
item item_1 = new item
{
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b'
};
string jsonPayload = serializer.Serialize(item_1);
var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonPayload);
stringContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "text/json";
content.Add(stringContent, item_1.GetType().Name);
// then it makes a network request
```

And if I had to make my best guess, here's what I think it would be doing in JS, although I must be a little bit off since the api is returning 415 Unsupported Media Type:

```
const item_1 = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}; 
const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify(item_1); 
const formData = new FormData(); 
formData.set('data', jsonPayload); 
fetch('/some_api/endpoint',{
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"text/json"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
});
```

If you need more info, or have questions, or suggestions on how to improve the post, please comment! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Content-Type is post to be multipart/form-data; however, there's a catch.

Form data content type has a boundary at the end of it.

What my colleagues do is simply not define Content-Type and let it be automatically determined. That way it would have the correct boundary.

On another note. If you are only sending JSON; then, if possible, you should not use form data; but, rather json. Form data is only really required if you are trying to send multiple types of data. Such as text and an image at the same time.

Comment: Marking this as correct because the API is indeed expecting a FormData object, and explicitly deleting the `Content-Type` header before sending the request, so that thew browser can set that property automatically, is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a FormData object? I think you want to just send the contents as JSON;

```
const item_1 = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
}; 
const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify(item_1); 
fetch('/some_api/endpoint',{
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"text/json"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: jsonPayload 
});
```

From this documentation page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) it seems that would not be JSON content type;

> It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were
>   set to "multipart/form-data".

Comment: Best not to ask questions in answers (particularly when it can seem sarcastic). And this was exactly what I was thinking. :-)

Comment: It's the whole `content = new MultipartFormDataContent();` and `content.Add(stringContent, item_1.GetType().Name);` that made me think there was an extra step that's important to get right. I did previously, and again just now, try a normal JSON POST and also a multipart/form-data, but no dice..